# aws ec2 ssh fails after creating an image of the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I regularly create an image of a running instance without stopping it first. That has worked for years without any issues. Tonight, I created another image of the instance (without any changes to the virtual server settings except for a "sudo yum update -y") and noticed my ssh session was closed. It looked like it was rebooted after the image was created. Then the web console showed 1/2 status checks passed. I rebooted it a few times and the status remained the same. The log showed:

```
Setting hostname localhost.localdomain:  [  OK  ]

Setting up Logical Volume Management: [    3.756261] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
[  OK  ]

Checking filesystems
Checking all file systems.
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /] fsck.ext4 -a /dev/xvda1 
/: clean, 437670/1048576 files, 3117833/4193787 blocks
[/sbin/fsck.xfs (1) -- /mnt/pgsql-data] fsck.xfs -a /dev/xvdf 
[/sbin/fsck.ext2 (2) -- /mnt/couchbase] fsck.ext2 -a /dev/xvdg 
/sbin/fsck.xfs: XFS file system.
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/xvdg
/dev/xvdg: 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
[    3.811304] random: crng init done
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

[FAILED]


*** An error occurred during the file system check.
*** Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot
*** when you leave the shell.
/dev/fd/9: line 2: plymouth: command not found
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue):
```

---

It looked like /dev/xvdg failed the disk check. I detached the volume from the instance and reboot. I still couldn't ssh in. I re-attached it and rebooted. Now it says status check 2/2 passed but I still can't ssh back in and the log still showed issues with /dev/xvdg as above.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Thomas

Comment: Have you tried attaching the underlying volume to a different instance, and trying to investigate from there?

Comment: Hi Marcin! Thank you for your comment. I mounted the volume using another instance, but it gave the same error. I then mounted the new EBS image that was created from this volume and got the same error. :/